# What is the leading "." used for before method or variable?

Tags: vba

What does this line mean.

```
.Criteria.FilterTagSet = True
```

This [page](https://docs.predix.io/en-US/content/historian/apis_and_sdk/historian_sdk/method-reference) has code written in this way.

Comment: If it starts with a `.` that means it is referencing an above `With` statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement

Comment: So `With xyz .abc = t .pqr = o`is same as `xyz.abc = t xyz.pqr = o` ?

Comment: yes. it is the same

Comment: @rs4 don't forget you need to close your `With` statement with an `End With`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example *by itself* will cause an error.

The dot syntax is used to access functions or members of objects or it is used to access members of user defined types or an enumeration.

Here's an example in Excel VBA using the global `Application` object:

```
Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = 1234
```

Another example with user defined types:

```
Type coordinate
    x As Double
    y As Double
End Type

Sub test()
    Dim point1 As coordinate
    Dim point2 As coordinate

    point1.x = point2.y * 2
End Sub
```

And lastly with enumerations. The following uses the inbuilt enumeration for days of the week:

```
Debug.Print VbDayOfWeek.vbWednesday
```

VBA supports a shorthand syntax where you need to use the same object repeatedly. For example:

```
Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = 1234
Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2) = 2345
Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3) = 3456
```

can be written shorthand as:

```
With Application.ActiveSheet
    .Cells(1, 1) = 1234
    .Cells(1, 2) = 2345
    .Cells(1, 3) = 3456
End With
```

if you want an easy way to remember it just think of it as "**With** respect to object X".

You can also use the `With` syntax with user defined types. But you can't use it with enumerations.